# Select record for each type + sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

Table `A1`:

```
A1Id   A1Type
 1      ABC
 2      XYZ
 3      PQR
```

Table `B1`:

```
 B1Id   B1Name        A1Id
  1     asia           1
  2     asian          1
  3     aftric         2
  4     angloafric     2
  5     aftricegypt    2
  6     usa            3
  7     redindian      3
```

Now I need get one matching record from Table B1 for each type in A1.

I need to get these results:

```
B1Id        B1Name     A1Id
---------------------------
1           asia       1
2           aftric     2
3           redindian  3
```

I need to write a select query to fetch at least a single matching record for each record.

Can someone advise how to write query?

Comment: why is usa not included in the result?

Comment: its just a randam..I just thought that the users should not think in the way that I only want the first one in a table. Atleast one matching I need.

Answer (score 0):

If USA is OK, 
and i use A1ID as New B1Id

then Try this below sql

assuming table @A1 is table A1 and table @B1 is table B1

```
with cte as
(
select 
    b.B1Id,b.B1Name
    ,a.A1ID
from @A1 a
inner join @B1 b on  a.A1ID = b.A1Id
)
select  
    C1.A1ID as B1ID
    ,c1.B1Name
    ,C1.A1ID
from cte c1
left join cte c2 on c1.A1ID = c2.A1ID and c1.B1Id = c2.B1Id + 1
where c2.B1Id is null


B1ID        B1Name               A1ID
----------- -------------------- -----------
1           asia                 1
2           aftric               2
3           usa                  3
```